# Seleccionar el anterior y posterior a un elemento en una única consulta

Tags: mysql

Selecciona, a partir de un id, el próximo y el anterior que contenga una característica (basada en el `WHERE`).

Algo así (en pseudo-código):

```
SELECT id 
FROM tabla DESDE LA CELDA DONDE id = x , EL SIGUIENTE Y EL ANTERIOR 
WHERE nombre="fulanito";
```

Comment: no logro entender bien lo que quieres

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que caracteristica? de que estas hablando? no se entiende tu pregunta.

Comment: Las preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo. Lee [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic) y [ask] para más información.

Comment: Creo que tu idea es buena. Y lo que tienes podría funcionar con pocos cambios. Por ejemplo, creando una tabla temporal sólo con los valores del where y buscar el id solo en esa tabla para quedarte con las filas anterior y posterior.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que eso sea un procedimiento que le entra una variable X:

```
call procedimiento_mio(X);
```

Y la sentencia SQL sería así:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE nombre="fulanito" AND id = @X-1 and id = @X+1;
```

Tienes que buscar como hacer un procedimiento y el uso de variables, y pensar que si el id es:

- 0
- No existe
- Es el último

Te dará error.

Comment: Esto puede no funcionar como se pide en la pregunta (o necesitaría algo más). Por ejemplo, imagina que para los IDs 1 a 5, los nombres son Diego, Fulanito, Ricardo, Fulanito, y Fulanito respectivamente; y se pasa el ID 4. El resultado esperado sería 2 y 5 (los IDs de las entradas con nombre Fulanito anterior y siguiente a la de ID 4), pero con esta solución se devolvería 3 y 5 (a pesar de que el ID 3 tendría el nombre Ricardo que no cumple con la condición).

Comment: No había entendido bien la pregunta, gracias por la explicación, y la única manera que veo para resolverlo es usando apuntadores para recorrer la tabla haciendo una búsqueda desde el ID.

Comment: Me gustaría saber si tiene que ser necesariamente escrito en SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar subquerys con el max() y el min() si sabes el id. Por ejemplo

```
 select anterior, posterior from 
      (select max(id) "anterior"  from tabla  where id < 10) as previa, 
      (select min(id) "posterior"  from tabla  where id > 10) as posterior
```

Puedes sustituir el valor "10" por el nombre de un campo

Answer (score -1):

ESTO AYUDA , DE TODAS FORMAS SI TIENEN RESPUESTA POR FAVOR PUBLÍCALA. =)

SELECT * FROM `movierentals` WHERE `return_date` < '2012-06-25' AND movie_returned = 0;

Comment: explica tu respuesta, pues solo escribir código se considera de baja calidad